# updateURL and updateLink don't work in my addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I was reading the [cfx tool documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/cfx-tool.html), about how to create an addon and make it autoupdade automaticaly. Unfortunately when I compile my addon to an xpi file with this line:

```
cfx xpi --update-link "http://mypage.com/firefox/latest"
        --update-url "http://mypage.com/firefox/update_rdf"
```

I always get complains that the resulting xpi file is incompatible with Firefox 12.0. When I remove the `--update-link` and `--update-url` arguments the xpi file works. Am I missing something?

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4247192/firefox-add-on-doesnt-work-with-tag-emupdateurl/4253956#4253956) but unfortunately that solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should do:

1. Make sure you are using the latest version of the Add-on SDK. Add-on SDK 1.7 declares the add-ons as compatible with Firefox 12 and 13, previous versions didn't.
2. Make sure to upload the generated `update.rdf` file to `http://mypage.com/firefox/update_rdf`, you probably have an older file there. This file also contains compatibility information for the extension and Firefox trusts this information more than `install.rdf` inside the extension (this is useful to mark an extension as compatible with a newer Firefox version without actually updating the extension package).